# String.Compare doesn't work on greater case

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare string values:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int cmpValue = String.Compare("N-1.2.0.10", "N-1.2.0.8", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if(cmpValue > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("greater");

        cmpValue = String.Compare("N-1.2.0.10", "N-1.2.1.10", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if(cmpValue < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("lesser");

        cmpValue = String.Compare("N-1.2.0.10", "N-1.2.0.10", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if(cmpValue == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("equal");
    }
}
```

[This prints:](http://ideone.com/AyMSb3)

```
lesser
equal
```

For some reason, the `greater` case doesn't print.  Why isn't `"N-1.2.0.10"` considered greater than `"N-1.2.0.8"`?

Comment: The 1 is less than the 8 when comparing character by character (it is not a numeric comparison).

Comment: You'll need to parse out the numeric values and compare them to get the results you want.

Comment: I always love these _optimistic programming_ questions. `Twelve` is greater than `Pi`, but `Three` sorts between them. And `III` doesn't equal `3` or `Three`! Why doesn't .NET do the right thing?

Comment: Is the `N-` part a constant, or it can also change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would it? String comparisons are performed character by character (with a few possiblt exceptions that do not apply here), and `'1'` compares as less than `'8'`.

The type of sorting you're looking for, where `"10"` compares as greater than `"8"`, is often called a "natural sort", for which .NET Framework doesn't provide any options directly, but which is easy to create yourself ([or let the native WinAPI do the work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/248613)).

Comment: Natural ordering was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Another option here would be to pull out the part that is obviously a version number and use the `Version` class to parse and compare the values.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because the strings are ordered alphabetically, not numerically:

```
10
11
12
20
8
etc.
```